# How to convert XML based XLS file to XLSX?

Tags: powershell, powershell-v6.0

I have a bunch of XLS files. On opening the file I got the prompt: `format and extension don't match`

Later, I found out that this is an old XML based XLS file. For that reason I couldn't directly import those files into R or SAS.

I tried opening one and use Save as to save the file in any format supported by R and SAS like XLSX or CSV etc.

The problem is there are hundreds of files, not quite viable to open and save as one by one.

Any process will be great that I can incorporate into PowerShell process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this powershell solution:

```
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application

foreach ($File in (gci *xls)) {
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName) 
$Workbook.SaveAs(($File.FullName + "x"), 51) 
$Workbook.Close($false)}

$Excel.Quit()
```

Or if you want the files in csv:

```
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application

foreach ($File in (gci *xls)) {
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName) 
$Workbook.SaveAs($File.FullName.Replace(".xls",".csv"), 6) 
$Workbook.Close($false)}

$Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Do you know if that will open the XML files that have been saved with .xls extension without causing a pop-up window to confirm opening file whose content doesn't match the extension?  It would be a pain to have to confirm hundreds of file opens.

Comment: I don't think so, but if it does you may use the CorruptLoad property of the Open method to specify that you want to use the repair mode in Excel https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open